# Tracking average of two progress bar with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm developing a very important project where the user can change the values of "pressure" of two elements via checkboxes.
These checkboxes has two different values, one for `bar-one` and the second for `bar-two`. All this system has a "status panel" that says if it's all ok, or if there's a problem.

Please note that I don't have to use echoes or alert messages, because I need to show different div's depending on the current status of both bars.

I did the best I can in the snippet, I'm new to JavaScript so please don't be mean with my errors.

```js
var 
    even = $('.even'),
    high = $('.high'),
    low = $('.low');

$('input').on('click', function() {
    var emptyValue = 0;
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        emptyValue += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('.bar-one').css('width', emptyValue + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', emptyValue);
});

if (average === 5) {
    even.show();
  } else {
    even.hide();
  }
  
if (average >= 7) {
    high.show();
  } else {
    high.hide();
  }
  
if (average <= 3) {
    low.show();
  } else {
    low.hide();
  }
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: silver;
}

.bar-one {
  background-color: blue;
}

.bar-two {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar-one" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar-two" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="panel">
    <input type="checkbox" value1="20" value2="5">
    <input type="checkbox" value1="5" value2="20">
    <input type="checkbox" value1="10" value2="10">
    <input type="checkbox" value1="10" value2="-20">
    <input type="checkbox" value1="-20" value2="10">

</div>

<div class="even">
  Pressure is ok
</div>
<div class="high">
  Pressure is high
</div>
<div class="low">
  pressure is low
</div>
```

Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: what is the problem that you get when run the script ?

Comment: Please run the snippet, I can't see anything working =(

Comment: First change the event from click to select

Comment: Use $("input[type=checkbox]");      Change event to select instead of click define high low and even variables inside the select function and see the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly how you want it to go. But this is how I would do it. Maybe looking at what I did you can figure out what you want to do.

```js
var 
    even = $('.even'),
    high = $('.high'),
    low = $('.low');
    
var averageCount = $("#panel").find("input").length;
var average = 0; // not sure how you are calculating average so i just added this.

updateStatus(average); // just to start message boxes as default;

$('input').on('click', function() {

    var emptyValue1 = 0;
    var emptyValue2 = 0;
    
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        emptyValue1 += parseInt($(this).attr("data-value1"));
        emptyValue2 += parseInt($(this).attr("data-value2"));
    });
    
    
    average = (emptyValue1+emptyValue2)/averageCount;
    
    $('.bar-one').css('width', emptyValue1 + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', emptyValue1);
    
    $('.bar-two').css('width', emptyValue2 + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', emptyValue2);
    
    updateStatus(average); // update the message box
});


function updateStatus(average){
  if (average === 5) {
      even.show();
    } else {
      even.hide();
    }

  if (average >= 7) {
      high.show();
    } else {
      high.hide();
    }

  if (average <= 3) {
      low.show();
    } else {
      low.hide();
    } 
}
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: silver !important;
}

.bar-one {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

.bar-two {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar-one progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"  style="width:0%">
    
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar-two progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="panel">
    <input type="checkbox" data-value1="20" data-value2="5">
    <input type="checkbox" data-value1="5" data-value2="20">
    <input type="checkbox" data-value1="10" data-value2="10">
    <input type="checkbox" data-value1="10" data-value2="-20">
    <input type="checkbox" data-value1="-20" data-value2="10">

</div>

<div class="even">
  Pressure is ok
</div>
<div class="high">
  Pressure is high
</div>
<div class="low">
  pressure is low
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not initializing the variable average. I put it on three and the rest of the code seems to work.

```js
var 
    even = $('.even'),
    high = $('.high'),
    low = $('.low'),
    average = 3;

$('input').on('click', function() {
    var emptyValue = 0;
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        emptyValue += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('.bar-one').css('width', emptyValue + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', emptyValue);
});

if (average === 5) {
    even.show();
  } else {
    even.hide();
  }
  
if (average >= 7) {
    high.show();
  } else {
    high.hide();
  }
  
if (average <= 3) {
    low.show();
  } else {
    low.hide();
  }
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: silver;
}

.bar-one {
  background-color: blue;
}

.bar-two {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar-one" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar-two" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="panel">
    <input type="checkbox" value1="20" value2="5">
    <input type="checkbox" value1="5" value2="20">
    <input type="checkbox" value1="10" value2="10">
    <input type="checkbox" value1="10" value2="-20">
    <input type="checkbox" value1="-20" value2="10">

</div>

<div class="even">
  Pressure is ok
</div>
<div class="high">
  Pressure is high
</div>
<div class="low">
  pressure is low
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but I can't see any result on the progress bars or in the status. Thanks anyways!